# C# and selenium: selectByText using a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, selenium, drop-down-menu

I have a list of elements that am unable to call from a selectByText. If I use "Test1" instead of dropdownLists[i], the code works, however I want to loop through a list of 10 items

Code:

```
static void dropdownLists()
{
    dropdownList = new List<string>();
    dropdownList.Add("Test1");
    dropdownList.Add("Test2");
    dropdownList.Add("Test3");                
}
```

//Used in a for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < dropdownList.Count; i++)
{
       System.Console.WriteLine("dropdownList: {0}", dropdownList[i]);
       new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("DocumentType")))
       .SelectByText(dropdownLists[i]);
       Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
}
```

---

The error I receive is:

Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'  C:\myCSharp\mySelenium\mySelenium\ProgramCRM1.cs    76  91  myInfoCenter

Error   3   Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'   C:\myCSharp\mySelenium\mySelenium\ProgramCRM1.cs    76  91  myInfoCenter

Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement.SelectByText(string)' has some invalid arguments C:\myCSharp\mySelenium\mySelenium\ProgramCRM1.cs    76  17  myInfoCenter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier things to do in this case will be `SelectByIndex(i)` You are over complicating the implementation I guess

If you want to stick to your plan I guess the following is a better option as well:

```
var selectElement = new SelectElement(Driver.FindElement(By.Id("DocumentType")));
int options = selectElement.Options.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < options; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(selectElement.Options[i].Text);
}
```

**EDIT**

To meet OP's criteria

```
By byXpath = By.XPath("//select[@id='DocumentType']");

//wait for the element to exist
new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(byXpath));

IWebElement element = Driver.FindElement(byXpath);
var selectElement = new SelectElement(element);
int options = selectElement.Options.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < options; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(selectElement.Options[i].Text);

    //in case if other options refreshes the DOM and throws StaleElement reference exception
    new SelectElement(Driver.FindElement(byXpath)).SelectByIndex(i);

    //do the rest of the stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help                                             The code compiled with no errors. However I receive a runtime exception                                                NoSuchElementException was unhandled
Unable to find element with id == DocumentType

Comment: That's a different issue now. Can you provide the html of entire select element?

Comment: <form action="/Home/Attachments/B1C56889-54D6-E211-ACC3-0050569D4561" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"><input id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="B1C56889-54D6-E211-ACC3-0050569D4561" />

Comment: <div class="DocumentType">
<select id="DocumentType" name="DocumentType">                                                <option value="">Select Document Type</option>
<option value="1">Test1</option>
<option value="2">Test2</option>
<option value="3">Test3</option>
</select>
    </div>
    <div class="FileUpload">
        <input type="file" name="FileUpload" id="fileUpload" />
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
    <span id="Message" class="error"></span>
</form>
<div class="AttachmentGrid">

Comment: Are you trying to print the options only?

Comment: I am try to loop through each option e.g when I have test1, I need to identify element and then get a screenshot. Then upload a document and get another screenshot

Comment: see my edit and added code. Let me know if you encounter any issue

Comment: I appreciate you accept the answer. Please upvote as well if it helps

Comment: Thank you so much! Perfect solution, you are awesome. How do I learn to debug like you? Any suggestions for a tutorial link is much appreciated.

Comment: I am writing selenium tests for more than a year. I use Visual Studio which is a very powerful tool for debugging and even youtube and http://channel9.msdn.com/  have lot of videos how to debug on VS. There is no magic I guess I spent a lot of time on SO and read

Comment: Thank you, I do not have enough reputation to up vote. Just joined member here, when I have enough reputation I will vote.

Answer (score 2):

The error message pretty much told you everything you need.

1. `'OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement.SelectByText(string)' has some invalid arguments`. So you're not passing a string to the method.
2. `Error 3 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'`.  What? [] cannot be applied to `dropdownLists`?  Why?
3. `Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'`. Oh, that is because `dropdownLists` is a function name, not a variable!

Now you should know your mistake: you used a function name `dropdownLists` instead of variable name `dropdownList`.

BTW, try to name your function better.  Usually adding a verb in the beginning will make things much clearer.  For example, `getDropdownList` or `populateDropdownList`.

Comment: Thank you for your help                                             The code compiled with no errors. However I receive a runtime exception                                                NoSuchElementException was unhandled
Unable to find element with id == DocumentType

Comment: If such exception is thrown, how is it possible that you said "If I use "Test1" instead of dropdownLists[i], the code works"?  Could you tell us more about the `driver` variable?

Comment: If I  select the element without Index or for loop the code works but I have to repeat it 10 times for each dropdown element e.g    new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("DocumentType"))).SelectByText("Test1");                                                                    new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("DocumentType"))).SelectByText("Test2");